# Переход на страницу по условию

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html> <text javascript=""> <script> var val = $("input[name=name_of_input]").val(); if (val == 1) document.location.href='65.html'; else if (val == 2) document.location.href='43.html'; else alert("Данный код в баззе не хранится!"); </script> </html>
```

Comment: @Александр Гижевский, уделяйте, пожалуйста, больше внимания заголовкам ваших тем. Они должны нести смысловую нагрузку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery:

```
    <script>
    var val = $("input[name=name_of_input]").val();
    if (val == 65) document.location.href='65.html';
     else if (val == 43) document.location.href='43.html';
    else alert("Данный код в баззе не храниться!");
    </script>
```

Comment: я чуть- чуть изменил вопрос прочитайте!

Comment: ну поменяй val соответственно на 1 и 2

Comment: <script>
    var val = $("input[name=name_of_input]").val();
    if (val == 1) document.location.href='65.html';
     else if (val == 2) document.location.href='43.html';
    else alert("Данный код в баззе не храниться!");
    </script>

Comment: Спасибо. Можете мне дать свой скайп, я хочу вам еще вопрос задать.
Что тут не так?

    <html>
    <text/javascript>
    <script> 
    var val = $("input[name=name_of_input]").val(); if (val == 1) document.location.href='65.html'; else if (val == 2) document.location.href='43.html'; else alert("Данный код в баззе не храниться!"); 
    </script>
    </html>

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так, на чистом javascript:

```
var val = getElementById('айдишник поля').value;
if (val == 65 || val == 43) document.location.href = val+'.html';
else alert("Данный код в баззе не хранится!");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var baza = {65: 1, 43: 1}, znachenie = document.getElementById('pole').value;
if(baza[znachenie]){
    location.href = znachenie + '.html';
}
else{
    alert('=(');
}
```

Номера страниц хранятся в объекте на случай, если надо будет задать какие-либо дополнительные параметры при открытии страницы.